# Unable to run .robot files in Eclipse Oxygen in Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, robotframework

I have a Mac laptop and have installed RED in Eclipse Oxygen version. When I try to run a .robot file in Eclipse I see the popup RunTime Environment Error with the message "Unable to provide valid RED environment. Check python/ robot installation and set it in Preferences". I do not see this issue in Windows machine.

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables and/or googled this issue? It seems like a config issue with the RED environment

Comment: have you verified that the red.xml, which is your project configuration, points to a Python interpreter?

Comment: I set the path in Eclipse-> Preferences. However now I see the error "There is no active runtime environment for project" while running a .robot file from Eclipse

Comment: I have set the path in Installed Frameworks. Now when I run the .robot file I see the error "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home." I have copied Chromedriver to Python 2.7 folder.

Answer (score 0):

This errors tells that RED could not found Python+Robot installation using command which/whereis. This can be verified by going to Windows->Preferences->RobotFramework -> Installed Frameworks. That part should show you list of python interpreters with robot - in your case either could be empty (no python found) or entry with red color (python without robot found).

On Windows usually Python is added to PATH so it is visible and discovered by RED, somehow Mac does not do this by default (you are not the first person with such issue).

Go to Windows->Preferences->RobotFramework -> Installed Frameworks, there is Add.. button and provide path where python executable is located. I do not have MacOS to provide you usual path, under linux (Centos,Ubuntu) it is in /usr/bin . **Take note that RED looks for python filename, if your installation renamed it to python3,python2,py2,py3 or other just make a copy to python.**

I will make an Help topic about finding python installations when python is not in PATH as it seems it is more common than I fought.
If you have any other questions, it is better to create GitHub issue: https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues

Comment: I have set the path in Installed Frameworks. Now when I run the .robot file I see the error "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home."; I have copied Chromedriver to Python 2.7 folder

Comment: this error : "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. : is from ChromeDriver/Selenium, and it says what should be done - find chromedriver and include that folder in PATH variable. Here is answer for that error : 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

It looks like you manage to set proper python + robot interpreter to RED,please mark my answer as correct. Now you are struggling with proper Selenium and ChromeDriver setup not connected with RED

Comment: I tried as mentioned above bit doesnt work, still I see the same error. Pls check

Comment: Not much I can help you with env setup for selenium as it is not my area of expertise. I propose to start another question with details what you have installed (version of env,python,robot,selenium and webdrivers etc.) either on robotframework tag or on selenium tag.